# Implicits and blackbox macros

Tags: scala, macros

I have the following code;

`def $q[U](selector: T => U, value: U)(implicit writer: BSONDocumentWriter[U]): BSONDocument = macro MacrosImpl.getBsonExpr[T, U]`

The code of getBsonExpr is;

```
def getBsonExpr[T, U](c: Context)(selector: c.Expr[T => Any], value: c.Expr[U])(implicit writer: BSONDocumentWriter[U]): c.Expr[BSONDocument] = {
    import c.universe._
    val helper = new Helper[c.type, T](c, selector)

    reify {
      val p = helper.pathStringExpr().splice
      val v = value.splice
      BSONDocument(p -> writer.write(v))
    }
  }
```

However you can't pass implicits to a macro, so when I compile I get:

`macro implementations cannot have implicit parameters other than WeakTypeTag evidences`

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
def $q[U](selector: T => U, value: U)(implicit writer: BSONDocumentWriter[U]): BSONDocument = macro MacrosImpl.getBsonExpr[T, U]
```

with

```
def getBsonExpr[T, U](c: Context)
  (selector: c.Expr[T => Any], value: c.Expr[U])
  (writer: c.Expr[BSONDocumentWriter[U]]): c.Expr[BSONDocument] = {
  <...>
}
```

You can of course not pass the instance of BSONDocumentWriter itself (only the expression tree) to the macro because, well it is a macro and does get compiled before your program.

I don't really know what your macro should do so I can't help you with the implementation. If you provide me with more details I can help you there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `c.inferImplicitValue`. A macro does not need to be passed implicit parameters, as it can directly look them up.

You have a problem on your `helper`, as you can't use params known at runtime during compile time. Fixing this depends on your intent.

Last tip. Use quasiquotes, as they are much more flexible than `reify`.

I would do something along these lines (not tested).

```
class A[T] {

def $q[U](selector: T => U, value: U): BSONDocument =
  macro MacrosImpl.getBsonExpr[T, U]

}

object MacrosImpl {

  def getBsonExpr[T, U: c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context)(selector: c.Expr[T => Any], value: c.Expr[U]): c.Expr[BSONDocument] = {
    import c.universe._

    // cannot work as selector is not known at compile time (only its tree his)
    // and macro code is evaluated at compile time
    val helper = new Helper[c.type, T](c, selector)

    // Look for implicit BSONDocumentWrite
    val writer = c.inferImplicitValue(appliedType(typeOf[BSONDocumentWriter[_]], List(weakTypeOf[U])))

    // In case no implicit
    if(writer = EmptyTree) sys.error("No implicit BSONDocumentWriter!")

    val tree = q"""
      val p = ${helper.pathStringExpr()}
      val v = $value
      BSONDocument(p -> $writer.write(v)
    """

    c.Expr[BSONDocument](tree)

  }

}
```

Comment: While I like the code at first sight the compiler complains about `c.inferImplicitValue(typeOf[BSONDocumentWriter])`. It says; `trait BSONDocumentWriter takes type parameters`. When I pass in `U` it misses a `TypeTag`. `WeakTypeTag` is not sufficient it seems.

Comment: My bad. I forgot `BSONDocumentWriter` took a type argument. I'll correct this shortly.